# How to view an email message file (located in a MailDir) from the command line?

Tags: email

I'm sure I once had a way to read email files from the commandline that was fall-off-a-log simple but I can't for the life of me find it again now.

I have files in MailDir format, I wish to view their contents (headers, body (HTML/plain), MIME-decoded, extract attachments maybe). These aren't my emails; it's not that I want a MUA capable of fetching, sorting, sending mail for me - they're just raw files that I need to inspect.

Comment: `cat` would work

Comment: `cat` can't decode mime or base64.   `mutt -f /path/to/Maildir` would work better.   But you're probably thinking of the ancient [MH aka Message Handling System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MH_Message_Handling_System), or `new MH` aka [nmh](https://www.nongnu.org/nmh/).   Command-line tools for manipulating mailboxes.   I'm not sure if the original MH could handle Maildir (probably not, Maildir is shiny  & new compared to MH) but New MH can.   BTW, this is packaged as `nmh` on debian.  Probably most other distros too.

Comment: @cas thanks, mutt works great as a UI for browsing a maildir, thanks. nmh looks plain scary: `mhshow` looked promising but won't do anything without me first setting up a mail account, talks about scanning and moving stuff: exactly what I don't want. @roaima: cat also can't handle flowed content.

Comment: Yeah, i first encountered MH about 30 years ago.  Ran screaming to `elm`.  After a brief dalliance with `pine`, I now use `mutt`.   I'll post my comment as an answer.

Comment: `elm` now there's a blast from the past. I misread the question and thought the last line meant that no decoding was necessary. Ooips.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package [maildir-utils](https://packages.debian.org/buster/maildir-utils) (at least it's called so in Debian) contains a program called `mu`, that has a nice functionality to display the contents of a Maildir mail message. It displays only the headers, the text/plain part plus list of attachments. See [man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/mu).

Example: `mu view /path/to/email-file`.

If you have an email with `text/html` MIME, `mu` can extract it to a separate file: `mu extract /path/to/email-file --parts=1` (which outputs to `1.msgpart` by default, assuming the HTML is the first part.)

Comment: This was it! Thanks @raj! I remembered it was a short command and that its usage was simple, too. Brilliant.

Answer (score 7):

Use `mutt -f /path/to/Maildir`.   Or `mutt -R -f /path/to/Maildir` if you want mutt to open the mailbox in read-only mode.

The command-line tools you're thinking of are probably **MH** aka [Message Handling System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MH_Message_Handling_System), which is ancient and un-maintained, or **[New MH](https://www.nongnu.org/nmh/)** which is still actively maintained.

I don't think the ancient `mh` can handle Maildir/ mailboxes, but `nmh` definitely can.

`nmh` is packaged as `nmh` on Debian, and probably on most other distros too.

Answer (score 2):

`reformime` is a command (from the `maildrop` package on Debian/Ubuntu) which can be used to extract the *body* of an email file.

You can get a list of MIME parts with `reformime -i <your-message` which gives you something like

```
section: 1
content-type: multipart/alternative
content-transfer-encoding: 8bit
charset: UTF-8
content-language: en-GB
starting-pos: 0
starting-pos-body: 2494
ending-pos: 75170
line-count: 1287
body-line-count: 1241

section: 1.1
content-type: text/plain
content-transfer-encoding: 8bit
charset: utf-8
starting-pos: 2578
starting-pos-body: 2666
ending-pos: 8180
line-count: 181
body-line-count: 178

section: 1.2
content-type: multipart/related
content-transfer-encoding: 8bit
charset: UTF-8
starting-pos: 8220
starting-pos-body: 8303
ending-pos: 75128
line-count: 1054
body-line-count: 1051

section: 1.2.1
content-type: text/html
content-transfer-encoding: 8bit
charset: utf-8
starting-pos: 8343
starting-pos-body: 8415
ending-pos: 25276
line-count: 343
body-line-count: 340
```

And then you can extract a section with `reformime -e -s 1.1` e.g. this would extract the plain text version (1.1). Likewise, if section 1.2.3 is an image you could view it like `reformime -e -s 1.2.3 <mail.eml | display :-`

So if you just want to see the plain text version you can 'easily' do it with a handy one-liner:

```bsh
F=/path/to/the-email-file
reformime -e -s $(reformime -i <$F | fgrep -B1 'content-type: text/plain' | head -n1 | cut -c 10- ) <$F
```

This is not quite the easy option I'd hoped to find, but thought I'd document it anyway!